# Multiple memcached bins on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, memcached

I just installed memcached on ubuntu 11.04 (which is my development server). During the install, the script arranged for memcached to be started automatically at boot. Great, just what I needed.

Except, I need 2 (or possibly 3) different memcached bins (in other words, one on port 11211, one one 11212) but I can't find where to configure ubuntu to start both memcached instances at boot time...

I'm currently using memcached 1.4.5

Per request, my /etc/init.d/memcached files looks like:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             memcached
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:         $local_fs
# Should-Stop:          $local_fs
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Start memcached daemon
# Description:          Start up memcached, a high-performance memory caching daemon
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/memcached
DAEMONBOOTSTRAP=/usr/share/memcached/scripts/start-memcached
NAME=memcached
DESC=memcached
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
test -x $DAEMONBOOTSTRAP || exit 0

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Edit /etc/default/memcached to change this.
ENABLE_MEMCACHED=no
test -r /etc/default/memcached && . /etc/default/memcached

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
  if [ $ENABLE_MEMCACHED = yes ]; then
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMONBOOTSTRAP
        echo "$NAME."
        else
                echo "$NAME disabled in /etc/default/memcached."
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
        echo "$NAME."
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        ;;

  restart|force-reload)
        #
        #       If the "reload" option is implemented, move the "force-reload"
        #       option to the "reload" entry above. If not, "force-reload" is
        #       just the same as "restart".
        #
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        sleep 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMONBOOTSTRAP
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc $DAEMON $NAME
        ;;
  *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, If you read the file /etc/init.d/memcached, you can see this

FILES=(/etc/memcached_*.conf).

So, I believe if you just create a memcached_1.conf file, with the settings, then it will run one more memcached process with the new port (given in the file created by you).

You can take the sample file from /etc/memcached.conf and copy it to /etc/memcached_1.conf.

just replace the default port 11211, with what you need, like 11212.

And restart the system. It should run the one more memcached binary with the new port and configs.

Comment: The line with "FILES..." is missin gin my /etc/init.d/memcached file, probably an other version of memcached? I'm using 1.4.5

Comment: Hmmm .. Could be. Can you please paste your /etc/init.d/memcached file here so that I can check the same.

Comment: Ok, I added it to my original question so I could layout it properly. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmmm .. it's different. Do you have any idea where do you set the port number for memcached. That should be the key file for the settings. If you can find the same, is there any way you could share the contents of the same.

Comment: Can't really say that I do... Correction, I found the answer here, but still no idea on how to setup multiple instances: http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/how-to-install-memcached-in-ubuntu/

Comment: This is not a solution for this problem on Ubuntu 11.04, but by now I found the time to upgrade to 12.04 an yes, there it is that simple.

Comment: This answer is correct.  This same question has been solved at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928387/how-can-we-create-two-instances-of-memcached-server-in-same-server-in-different